# How can I connect my Leap Motion with Android device Samsung Tablet A?

Tags: android, leap-motion

I am dealing with Leap Motion but I need the SDK for Android or driver installer for Leap Motion on my tablet, so it can communicate with it.

Any help, please?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I connect leap motion to my Tablet device ?

Answer (score 0):

We have a private Android alpha in place, though it's limited to devices running Snapdragon 800+ chips. There's more about it in this post: https://community.leapmotion.com/t/android-sdk-hardware-requirements/2845.